Is this the CDF of a known probability distribution?
Consider the following cumulative distribution function over $\mathbb{R}^{+}$
$F\left(x\right)\;=\;1+\mathcal{W}\left(-e^{-1-x}\right)$
where $\mathcal{W}\left(\cdot\right)$ is the Lambert W function.
Does it correspond to a known probability distribution with a name? If yes, can you provide a reference?

to add to the discussion: according to mathematica, the associated PDF is $\frac{1}{1+W(-e^{-1-x})}-1$.

It seems to have an expectation of $\frac12$ and variance of $\frac{7}{12}$ and a quantile function of $x = - p - \log(1-p)$

Not very relevant, but if instead it had had a quantile function of $x = - \log(1-p)$ then it would have been an exponential distribution with expectation and variance $1$.

@henry, a mixture model then?

@EngrStudent - I doubt it
